# accessing PART of a file name based on user input to a function--Python

Tags: python

I'm a newb trying to figure out how to accomplish the following:

I have dicts named after users in the following format:

```
<user>_hx
```

I want to access them with a function like so:

```
def foo(user, other_stuff):
  user_hx[key]
```

......etc.

I attempted to access with % as follows:

```
def foo(user, other_stuff):
  %r_hx %user[key]
```

but for obvious reasons I know that can't work.

Adivce?

Comment: how about `eval(user+'_hx')`, although eval is not recommended

Comment: I don't see where you're accessing any files.

Comment: yeah Im missing something here... its not clear what you are trying to do... do you mean `"%s_hx"%user[key]` ? you open a file with `open(filename,fileMode)`

Answer (score 1):

What I think you are asking is how to access a variable based on a string representing its name. Python makes this quite easy:

```
globals()['%s_hx' % user]
```

will give you the variable `<user>_hx`, so you just want

```
globals()['%s_hx' % user][key]
```

(I'm not sure whether you should be using `globals()` or `locals()`; it will depend on how your variables are defined and where you are trying to access them from)

That said, there is probably an easier/cleaner way to do whatever you are doing. For instance, have you considered putting all these dictionaries in a 'master' dictionary so that you can pass them around, as well as just access them

Comment: Yeah, I would definitely not recommend doing this ever.  It's marginally better than `eval` but still worse than just using a dict of dicts which is what I'm guessing would be the right solution here.

Comment: There's no need to do this. Just put the dictionaries inside another dictionary. The `globals()` function just returns the global dictionary, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(user,other_stuff):
     fname = "%s_hx"%user[key] #not sure where key is comming from... but would result in something like "bob_hx"
     with open(fname) as f:
          print f.read()
```

maybe?/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the name as a variable. You can put your collection of dictionaries inside another, top-level, dictionary with those names as keys.

```
users = {
    "user1_hx": {"name": "User 1"},
    "user2_hx": {"name": "User 2"),
    }
```

etc.

Then access as:

```
realname = users["%s_hx" % name]["name"]
```

etc.